# T-SQL, eliminating specific accounts via value

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, where-clause

I would like to eliminate all accounts that contain any other value besides 2, then perform a count. Applying a `where Number = 2` will include Jim. I don't want Jim, I only want John. Example; This should pass.

```
+---------+-------+-------+--------+
| Account | First | Last  | Number |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+
| 17342   | John  | Locke | 2      |
| 17342   | John  | Locke | 2      |
| 17342   | John  | Locke | 2      |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+
```

This should not.

```
+---------+-------+------+--------+
| Account | First | Last | Number |
+---------+-------+------+--------+
| 20342   | Jim   | Look | 3      |
| 20342   | Jim   | Look | 2      |
| 20342   | Jim   | Look | 1      |
+---------+-------+------+--------+
```

After this I would like to find all accounts that do not have the value two in a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it.  One way (if you don't have too much data) would be something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Accounts
WHERE Account NOT IN (
    SELECT
        Account
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE Number <> 2
)
```

This would select all of your accounts where the account only contains a 2.

Comment: It's not the number of records which decides whether or not `NOT IN` works but if `Account` or `Numnber` can contain null values. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Account, First, Last, Number  
FROM dbo.Tablename t
WHERE t.Number = 2
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Tablename t2
   WHERE t.Account=t2.Account AND t.First=t2.First AND t.Last=t2.Last
   AND   t2.Number <> 2
)
```

This will select only records where there is no other record with the same account but a number <> 2. You can shorten it if the column `Account` is an identifier and `First`+`Last` belong to that  table.

Comment: Can you provide additional information regarding the WHERE NOT EXISTS? I am getting a wide array of incorrect information while i perform this operation. Thank you